# php send request to url and receive csv => need save this file in my server

Tags: php, csv, request, response, send

my link (URL) is different!!! and does not work with usual method

I have tested all methods (fetch, curl, file, get, put), but it does not work.

I have a similar URL here: 'http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx?h=0&r=0'

I can open it in the browser and download a csv file
I need to do this in php and **save the csv file on server**

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$page = fopen('http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx?h=0&r=0'); or $page = file_get_contents('http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx?h=0&r=0');
file_put_contents('http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx?h=0&r=0');
```

Comment: You'd want `file_get_contents` or use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to download the file to the server

Comment: my link is difterent and contents do not get csv!!! pls test my link !! @aynber

Comment: Your URL doesn't work, and I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: when open this url in browser , browser start download a CSV file with name "ClientTypeAll.csv "

Comment: "http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx?h=0&r=0"

Comment: with click dont work
but copy link and past in address bar its work and download a csv

Answer (score 0):

First things first: some of your function calls aren't correct, which might mean that your code doesn't even start requesting the file.
`fopen` expects two parameter where you are only giving it one. The first parameter is the resource location to open, in your case it is the URL, the second parameter it requires is the open mode, you'd probably want `r` here, which means read-only. This results in a resource that you'd need to read using `fread`, see more on the [fopen php.net page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Your `file_get_contents` call is correct in itself, but because of the `or` in front of it it will throw some kind of syntax error, but I am guessing the or is there for stackoverflow only

`file_put_contents` expects at least two parameters as well. It's first parameter is the filename to write to, which in your case would be something along the lines of `file.csv`, the second parameter is the data to write to the file, this is where you'd use the results of `fopen` stored in the `$page` variable, see more on the [file_put_contents php.net page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Assuming PHP has access to the file (if I click the link it won't open, might be some proxy issues or something) the following should work

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://example.com");
file_put_contents("some_file.csv", $page);
```